# Intercepting Fetch in javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch

I can detect every fetch inside my browser thanks to the js code below.

```
const nativeFetch = window.fetch;
window.fetch = function (...args) {
    console.log('Getting some data...');
    return nativeFetch.apply(window, args);
}
```

So every time user navigate inside my app, I can trace what is fetched.
Unfortunately it doesn't 'intercept' the last fetch showed on the picture below (in red). I don't know why. Because it fetch from another domain(*) ? Because it was blocked by CORS policy ?

(*) This fetch is from another domain: https://dev-123456.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?client_id=12122...

Do you have any idea if this is possible to 'detect' this fetch in javascript ?

With the script showed above, it detect every fetch except this one.

[image]

Comment: Pay attention to the last two rows in the DevTools. I guess it's a fetch call originally to `Affairs?...`, then a 302 redirect is followed. So, `fetch` was only called once.

Comment: Indeed and I need to intercept the last one (in red). Not succeed so far.

Comment: maybe you can use the following alternative to get the final request url. Intercept on a 302 redirect is hard due to `fetch's` implementation ```return nativeFetch.apply(window, args).then(res => {
      console.log(`fetch requested url ${res.url}`)
      return res;
    });```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on a plain old .js file so I cannot use statements like '.then(...'

Comment: @Bronzato `.then()` *is* plain old js

Comment: Yes you are right but unfortunately I didn't get the final request url (the red one).